# How to make custom layout grids more semantic?

Tags: css, sass

Say if I have a basic system for making my own grids.

BASE CSS:

```
.grid {
    @include clearfix;
    margin: 0 -1.5em;
}
.grid-unit {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
.layout .grid-unit {
    width: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid home-features">
    <div class="grid-unit"><!-- feature 1 --></div>
    <div class="grid-unit"><!-- feature 2 --></div>
    <div class="grid-unit"><!-- feature 3 --></div>
    <div class="grid-unit"><!-- feature 4 --></div>
</div>
```

RESPONSIVE:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .home-features .grid-unit {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
    .home-features .grid-unit {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

How do I go about making my own SASS mixins so the above can be more symantic? I don't need a full-blown solution as there are open-source frameworks out there one could look at. However, these frameworks are trying to do a lot of things at the same time and I am tearing my hair out trying to read the source. For example, they go through all kinds of loops to achieve the above. I just need a simple premise to get started with making a symantic solution for the above code.

Comment: What do you mean "making my SASS more semantic"? Semantic elements are defined in HTML (`<section>`, `<footer>`, `<kbd>`, ...) which are styled using CSS. The CSS doesn't change semantics, it merely provides an alternative view of the document.

Comment: I don't see the problem here.  You have the code you want, so turn it into a mixin?

Comment: @Daniel Imms I dont mean make my sass semantic. lol. I mean "making the above grid solution" sematic. So its not using any markup in html and css does all the heavy-lifting. Framewoks like bootstarp and foundation accomplish this with sass mixins, Read more here - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean more semantic *class names* then you should inspect the Foundation and Bootstrap source to see how they do it. Here is one approach:

```
@mixin media-lg {
  @media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin media-md {
  @media screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 59.9999999em) {
    @content;
  }
}

@include media-md {
  .lg-col-2 div {
    width:50%;
  }
  .lg-col-4 div {
    width:25%;
  }
}

@include media-lg {
  .lg-col-2 div {
    width:50%;
  }
  .lg-col-4 div {
    width:25%;
  }
}
```

*Compile online at http://sassmeister.com/*

On this markup for example:

```
<div class="lg-col-4 md-col-2">
    <div><!-- feature 1 --></div>
    <div><!-- feature 2 --></div>
    <div><!-- feature 3 --></div>
    <div><!-- feature 4 --></div>
</div>
```